# WorsPress orederby specific author name

Tags: wordpress, sql-order-by, posts

I would like to sort authors by specific name.

This is my code:

```
$authorname = 'max';

$blog_arr = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => '(author = "'.$authorname.'") desc'
);

$post_arr = get_posts($blog_arr);
```

Unfortunately WordPress filters my orderby in the core.

This answers also does not help:
[SQL Server - Order by case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666890/sql-server-order-by-case) ,
[Ordering by specific field value first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104055/ordering-by-specific-field-value-first), [How do I return rows with a specific value first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250156/how-do-i-return-rows-with-a-specific-value-first)

Thank you for help.
Best regards

Comment: $authorname = 'max';

$blog_arr = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => '(author = "'.$authorname.'"),'desc'
);

$post_arr = get_posts($blog_arr);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a working solution:

```
function get_user_posts() {

    $blog_arr = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );

    global $sc_user;
    $authorname = 'max';
    $sc_user = get_user_by('login', $authorname);

    add_filter('posts_join_request','edit_posts_join_request');
    add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');

    $post_arr = get_posts($blog_arr);

    remove_filter('posts_join_request','edit_posts_join_request');
    remove_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');

    return $post_arr;
}

function edit_posts_join_request($join_request_statement) {
    $join_request_statement .= "join wp_users ON wp_posts.post_author = wp_users.ID";
    return $join_request_statement;
}

function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {
    global $sc_user;
    $orderby_statement = 'CASE WHEN wp_users.user_login = "'.$sc_user->user_login.'" THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, wp_users.user_login';
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```